# How to show comments in teaser?

Tags: comments, 7, nodes

As the title says, I'm looking for a way to show the node comments in teaser. Anybody knows how to do?

Comment: Does Drupal commons have the display suite module?

Comment: Not by default. I've to install it?

Comment: that's the only way I know how to do it. I'm sure there is a coding way though.

Comment: Ok, i'll try with DS. And if i'ld like only to insert the default *add comment* drupal link?

Comment: I think it will work for that too. Sorry I can't check right now.

Comment: click on manage display and on the top right you should see a Teaser button which you need to click on.

Comment: do you solve your problem?

Comment: Hi Andrian, please forgive my delay in answering. I tried several solutions including node js comment, but your solution is best for the type of outcome I wanted to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [EVA module](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva), it provides a Views display plugin that allows the output of a View to be attached to the content of any Drupal entity, in your case the teaser.

"[Entity Views Attach: Use Views Almost Anywhere](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/entity-views-attach/)" contains a great tutorial about it.

Comment: @emanuele a pleasure ;-)